# Doesn't test Nunit on TFS

Tags: tfs, nunit

I have local tfs server 2012. In VS 2010 I created solution with library and NUnit tests. I check-in this solution to tfs, and try start build definition. This is project successful builds, but no one NUnit test execute. I made this instruction: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/10/tfs-2012-build-configure-nunit-to-run.html , but it didn't help me. So, why NUnit tests doesn't execute on tfs?

Answer (score 0):

You need configure the name of Test projects on build definition, like the image:

[image]

That param is to locate the test assemblies, if the name of the assemblies does not contain 'TESTE', the build process will not run tests's. Configure like the image or like the pattern to found the assemblies.

And be sure the NUnit's assemblies will be in worksapece when build get then your code.